# do for-of operators work for sequence.split

Tags: javascript

[text]  I'm a novice at js, so this craftmanship is pretty shoddy, and specifically with this code I made it all from scratch, so elements might be out of order and weird. Everything works, the problem that I'm encountering is the for..let of light sequence. Here, sequenceArray is supposed to split the sequence into an array with each number being a different array element. Then, I'm trying to use for..let to parse through each array value and convert it to a light value. The problem is, I get no output when I press the test button or even when I put it into other sections of the code. This is a simon says game. Let me know if I need to format the code better, and I will do. Thank You!

```
const colorsbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
console.log("are you there");
possibilities = ["0", '1', '2', '3'];
colorpossibilities = ['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red'];
let sequence = "";
start = document.getElementById("start");
reset = document.getElementById("reset");
let mySequence = "";
let j = 0
let eligibility = 0;
let lightColor = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const green = document.getElementById('green');
const yellow = document.getElementById('yellow');
const red = document.getElementById('red');
const blue = document.getElementById('blue');
const sequenceArray = sequence.split("");
let test = document.getElementById('test');


let l = sequence.length;
function makeGreen(){
    green.style.backgroundColor = "darkgreen"; 
}
function makeRed(){
    red.style.backgroundColor = 'darkred';
}
function makeYellow(){
    yellow.style.backgroundColor = '#8B8000'
}
function makeBlue(){
    blue.style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
}

let play = 0;


test.addEventListener("click", function(){
    for(let light of sequenceArray){
        console.log(light + "James");
    }
});

colorsbutton.forEach(function(color){
    color.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        if(eligibility ==1){const square = e.currentTarget.classList;
        console.log(play);
        
        if(square.contains("green")){
           j++;
            mySequence += "0";
            green.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            setTimeout(makeGreen, 500);
           
        } else if(square.contains('blue')){
            j++;
            mySequence += "1";
            blue.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            setTimeout(makeBlue, 500);

        } else if(square.contains('yellow')){
            j++;
            mySequence += "2";
            yellow.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            setTimeout(makeYellow, 500);
        } else if (square.contains('red')){
            j++;
            mySequence += "3";
            red.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            setTimeout(makeRed, 500);
        } 
        if(j === sequence.length && sequence == mySequence){
            console.log("moveon");
            play++;
        } else if(j === sequence.length && sequence !== mySequence){
            console.log("You failed");
        }
       let splitSequence = sequence.split("");
        
        console.log(mySequence);
        
    }
        
    });
});

function getRandomNumber(){
    
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
}

function moveSequence(n){
    
    for(let i=0; i<n;i++){
        sequence += possibilities[getRandomNumber()];
    }
}

start.addEventListener("click", function(){
   if(play % 2 == 0){ play++;
    moveSequence(1);
    j=0;
    eligibility = 1;
    mySequence = "";
console.log(sequence);
let l = sequence.length;
order = "";}
    else if(play % 2!== 0){
        console.log("No more playing");
    }
    for(let light of sequenceArray){
        console.log(light);
    }
});

reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Reset Successful");
    sequence = "";
    mySequence = '';
    j=0;
    play = 0;
    eligibility = 0;
})
```

Comment: `const sequenceArray = sequence.split("");` runs once when your code loads on your page, and at that point `sequence` has nothing in it (its empty), so `sequenceArray` will be an empty array. So when you click your `test` button `sequenceArray` will be empty

Comment: Is there a way to constantly update it whenever there's an input?

Comment: You should update it manually whenever there is an input. You can add elements to the end of it with [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)